# Symfony2/Doctrine use LENGTH in where and groupBy?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a table: `logCall`

```
id          name        out_number         in_number       duration
1         nameTest1       302               400              60
2         nameTest2       3232211           400              12
3         nameTest3       303               401              20
3         nameTest3       302               32323            10
4         nameTest4       111               302              10
```

This is the part of the code I handle:

```
 $q = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
    $q->select("name, out_number in_number, duration")
        ->from(MAUTIC_TABLE_PREFIX . 'logCall')
        ->where("LENGTH(in_number) = 3")
        ->andWhere("LENGTH(out_number) = 3")
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    $result = $q->execute()->fetchAll();
    return $result;
```

Now I want :

1. Get the value `out_number` and `in_number` with the value `length == 3` (the code I processed above has an error in `where("LENGTH(in_number) = 3")`) so it can't be retrieved.
2. If I want to groupBy by `out_number` and `in_number`, is it possible to use the same query, or do I have to separate another query. For example, I want groupBy `out_number` with code `302`. And it calculates total `duration` equal to `70`. And similarly `in_number = 302` has total `duration = 10`.

Please give me feedback so I can fix this.

My code above is incomplete and may not be syntactically correct. Please help me. I am new to PHP. I switched from Js. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use the `expr` from the querybuilder.

```php
$qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select("name, out_number in_number, duration")
    ->from(MAUTIC_TABLE_PREFIX . 'logCall')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->length('in_number'), 3)
    )
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->length('out_number'), 3)
    )
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

$result = $qb->execute()->fetchAll();
return $result;
```

I haven't tested this in real, but that should do the trick.

More information [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I did the same and got the message `Undefined method 'length'`.